# Echo integer with 0

Tags: php

Hi I'm wondering for the following output:

```
<?php 
echo 0500; // Output: 320
echo "<br>";
echo 500; //Output: 500
?>
```

Any little explanation about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP renders any integer starting with a `0` (zero) as an octal (base 8) integer. If you `echo` it, however, you will get its decimal value. The page for [Integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) in the PHP manual says:

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +).
>
> Binary integer literals are available since PHP 5.4.0.
>
> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.

**UPDATE:** It may or may not be a sweet formula, but Wikipedia recommends this one for the octal to decimal conversion:

[image]

In this formula, *a<sub>i</sub>* is an individual octal digit being converted, where *i* is the position of the digit (counting from 0 for the right-most digit).

Let’s convert 3736<sub>8</sub> to decimal:

3736<sub>8</sub> = (3×8<sup>3</sup>)+(7×8<sup>2</sup>)+(3×8<sup>1</sup>)+(6×8<sup>0</sup>) = 1536+448+24+6 = 2014<sub>10</sub>

Comment: Yes, i got it. How to compute it by human? Any sweet formula?

Comment: [PHP Integer Types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax)

Comment: To get "0500" echoed to the screen, use a string literal, something that won't be interpreted by PHP as a number: **`echo "0500";`** Octal  (base 8) numerics are: last digit: 1s position, second to last digit, 8s position, third to last digit: 64's position. An Octal value of `0500` is decimal value: `5*64 + 0*8 + 0*1`.

Comment: What do this mean to make 0500 be 320?

Comment: Hmmmm.. interesting.. now i know why.